# Django-CMS WYMeditor not correctly working on Nginx

Tags: django, django-cms, wymeditor

I am a new user to Django and Django Cms. 
on local machine 
all js, html,css files download well when i work with backend 
But on production when i  use text plugin  I can't get some files 
There are: 
GET http://example.com/admin/cms/page/15/edit-plugin/56/lang/uk.js/ 500 (Internal Server Error) 
GET http://example.com/admin/cms/page/15/edit-plugin/56/iframe/default/wymiframe.html/ 500 (Internal Server Error)   (Status Code:301 MOVED PERMANENTLY)

Where example.com - my own site:) 
File uk.js - i added by monkey patching. (everything work fine on local machine)
In my html code in local I have:

```
<iframe src="/static/cms/wymeditor/iframe/default/wymiframe.html" onload="this.contentWindow.parent.WYMeditor.INSTANCES[0].initIframe(this)"></iframe>
```

On production side:

```
<iframe src="iframe/default/wymiframe.html" onload="this.contentWindow.parent.WYMeditor.INSTANCES[0].initIframe(this)"></iframe>
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('core.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

my core urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from django.http import HttpResponse

urlpatterns = patterns('core.views', 

   url(r"^robots.txt$", lambda r: HttpResponse("User-agent: *\nDisallow: /", mimetype="text/plain")),
   url(r"^commissions/$","commissions", name = "commissions" ),
   url(r"^commissions/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/$","commissions", name = "comma" ),
   url(r'^news/', include('cmsplugin_news.urls'),{}),
   url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

WHen i do `python manage.py collectstatic`  - everything fine and i have all static files on my static folder
Please help me what i doing wrong ?

Comment: What version of Django CMS are you using? That will help us formulate an answer for your specific situation because Django CMS 3 was a large change.